# laravel custom request validation id

Tags: php, laravel

hi i have laravel project and im using custom request 
this is my request code

```
public function rules()
{
    if($this->method() == 'POST' and $this->ajax())
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'integer|min:1|unique:archive_categorys',
            'archive_category_name' => 'max:50|min:1|unique:archive_categorys',
            'archive_category_id' => 'nullable|integer|min:1|max:'.Archive_category::max('id'),
            'archive_category_max' => 'nullable|integer|min:1|',
            'archive_category_plus_value' => 'nullable|integer|min:1|',
            'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|max:2048',
        ];              
    }
    elseif($this->method() == 'PATCH' )
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'required|min:1|unique:archive_categorys,id,'.$this->id,
            'archive_category_name' => 'required|max:50|min:1|unique:archive_categorys,archive_category_name,'.$this->id,
            'archive_category_id' => 'nullable|min:1|max:'.Archive_category::max('id'),
            'archive_category_max' => 'nullable|integer|min:1|',
            'archive_category_plus_value' => 'nullable|integer|min:1|',
            'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|max:2048',
        ];          
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

now my problem with method patch

```
'id' => 'required|min:1|unique:archive_categorys,id,'.$this->id,
```

now if i tried to change archive_categorys with id 1 to 2 
if there is no archive_categorys  with id 2 its will update successfully but if there is anther archive_categorys  with id 2 its will pass and get error `1062 Duplicate entry`
so how can i check unique value in laravel when update thanks

Comment: The `id` column is your primary key right?

Comment: Also post is when you are inserting/creating a new entry snd patch is to update right?

Comment: yes the id is the primary key

Comment: When you get the error then just show the error in client side that this `ID` already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you have `POST` route creating a new entry, `id` should not be ideally sent from the frontend but should be added automatically as primary key from MySQL.

Also in your `PATCH` route, you should send an `id` to validate if it exists.

Please check updated validation :

```
public function rules()
{
    if($this->method() == 'POST' and $this->ajax())
    {
        return [
            'archive_category_name' => 'max:50|min:1|unique:archive_categorys,name',
            'archive_category_max' => 'nullable|integer|min:1',
            'archive_category_plus_value' => 'nullable|integer|min:1',
            'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|max:2048',
        ];              
    }
    elseif($this->method() == 'PATCH' )
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'required|exists:archive_categorys,id,',
            'archive_category_name' => 'required|max:50|min:1|unique:archive_categorys,archive_category_name,'.$this->input('id'),
            'archive_category_max' => 'nullable|integer|min:1',
            'archive_category_plus_value' => 'nullable|integer|min:1',
            'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png|max:2048',
        ];          
    }
    return [];
}
```